# customer says emails are bouncing back any reasons for this to be with php

Tags: php, email

Our customer says that the emails to the customer is bouncing back any reason for this in the configuration of the headers below at all but when i test it i recieve it fine to my google account so i do

```
 // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
 $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
 $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= "Reply-To: Teeth Whitening     Superstore<info@teethwhiteningsuperstore.com>\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Return-Path: Teeth Whitening Superstore      <info@teethwhiteningsuperstore.com>\r\n"; 
$headers .= "From: Teeth Whitening Superstore <info@teethwhiteningsuperstore.com>\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Organization:  Teeth Whitening Superstore\r\n"; 

// Mail it
 mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, "-f $from_address");
```

Comment: You should ask your customer to send you a bounced back mail. The mail header contains more information, why the mail possibly bounced.

Answer (score 0):

Its not very often that an email is bounced for a reason to do with hearders. Usually if the headers are incorrect or the client deems this message spam, it will be moved to the spam box.

If its bouncing, you should be getting an email in return.

A few things to try though:

- Remove All Whitespace
- Remove the '-f $from_address' it is not a valid mail parameter as far as I am aware. That is what your headers are for.

Also to check if the email is sending correctly do this

```
$success = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

If success is true, then the mail function proceeded correctly. (This doesn't mean it wasn't bounced).